# cryptsetup luksAddKey throwing 'Maximum keyfile size exceeded' error - fix? 14.04

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I am attempting to add a homekey entry to my `/etc/crypttab` in order to prevent entering a 3rd pass upon login on a 14.04 install w/ LUKS (root/swap/home). When I attempt to add the key using `cryptsetup luksAddKey` I get the maximum keyfile size exceeded error.

I have attempted to use the `--keyfile-size 512` argument to see if it would override it, but it did not fix it.

Also, is there a way to do this same process for the swap, so that I only have to enter one password at boot? Or would doing that sacrifice security?

Comment: Is the swap on a LUKS volume by itself, separate from the root and home LUKS volumes? It could also be a raw dm-crypt volume with a randomly generated key on each boot. Posting the outputs of `lsblk`, `cat /etc/fstab`, and `sudo dmsetup table` will help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the key file that you are trying to use is at least 8 KiB, which exceeds `cryptsetup`'s default maximum size. You can use the `--new-keyfile-size <size_in_bytes>` option to force `cryptsetup` to use the key, but I recommend using a random key with a smaller size, because a key that is larger than the master key of the LUKS volume offers no additional security over a key that is the same size as the master key (as long as the key material is truly random).

The maximum master key size for LUKS is 512 bits, but it can also be 256 bits. You can check the size of your master key by finding the size of "MK bits" in `sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/<device>`.

I suggest generating keys from `/dev/random`. For example, to generate a random 512-bit (64-byte) key:

```
head -c 64 /dev/random > luks_key
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will give this a try - Im sure it will fix it! the key was generated from /dev/random.

Is it possible to do this same setup for the swap as well? Its a long password to type twice :/

Comment: Hum, tried what you said and it allowed the command, however now its not mounting home :( Any easy way to fix this using manual recovery? Damn me

Comment: Simply adding a key with `cryptsetup luksAddKey` should not affect your set up in any way. You mentioned modifying `/etc/crypttab` in your question. Did you modify `crypttab` or `fstab`, and what commands exactly did you run to add the key?

Comment: Yes, I modified /etc/crypttab following the instructions here:
http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu

Its near the very bottom. Is there a easy way to use manual recovery to recover the crypttab? or do you see something wrong with that tut that would have caused it to not boot? All I changed was the --new-keyfile-size 8000 to reflect the key I had generated

 and Crypttab looked like this:

home UUID=UUIDHERE /root/homekey luks

Comment: To reiterate my answer, I recommend using a smaller key file so that you don't need to use `--new-keyfile-size` with `cryptsetup luksAddKey`; I don't know if crypttab supports truncating a key file. Anyway, it's easy to revert to using a password: boot into recovery, revert `crypttab` (the relevant line should be something like `home UUID=<uuid> none luks`), and rerun `update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: Thank you, and can I do the same procedure to link a key to the swap partition so that I do not need to double enter the passphrase?

Comment: Yes, if the swap partition is also in a LUKS volume.

Comment: Got it all fixed with the /root/homekey :) Thank you! Now if you could just let me know if I can create /root/swapkey for the swap, or does ubuntu not have a process for unlocking a luks swap partition?

Comment: So sorry I did not see the above comment confirming my question prior to asking again! I did repeat the process for swap and it worked! Thank you so much for your assistance, you deserve much internet karma :)

Last question - Is there any security disadvantage to having both of those key's load swap/home automatically? Im thinking no, because they are stored on the LUKS partition, which makes them as secure as my salt/passphrase.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it all worked out. As for security: if the generated key files are as strong as the corresponding master keys, then the only practical implication is that any attacker who manages to gain access to your root partition will also get access to the key files, which can allow them to decrypt your home and swap volumes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

FYI, for anyone that finds this, the hibernation will not work (but sleep will) with setting up a generated keyfile for the swap partition. Other than that, everything ended up working great.